# Why I am not able to write any command in cmd terminal of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm trying to type something in the terminal of VS Code, it does not show any character. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead cmd try to add powershell.

[image]

If does not work click on plus sign to add a new terminal.

If does not work restart studio code.